# Sublime Text 3 build problem Haml/jQuery $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, sublimetext3, haml, sublime-build

I'm using the sublime text 3 editor

### Error is the following

The loading of jquery reference should be correct..

### Is like this on file.haml

```
%script{ :src => "js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" , :type => "text/javascript"}
%script{ :src => "js/jquery-ui.min.js" , :type => "text/javascript"} 
%script{ :src => "js/submitEvent.js" , :type => "text/javascript"}
```

My file.js works the same on my webpage but, if i try to build it ...give this error

can someone explain to me why?

```
/home/utexm/Scrivania/Testing-20/customForm/js/submitEvent.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { $(document).ready(function(){
                                                              ^

ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/utexm/Scrivania/Testing-20/customForm/js/submitEvent.js:1:63)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:739:3)
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['/usr/bin/node', '/home/utexm/Scrivania/Testing-20/customForm/js/submitEvent.js']]
[dir: /home/utexm/Scrivania/Testing-20/customForm/js]
[path: /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/opt/node_moduler/bin/]
```

Comment: Are your scripts loaded asynchronously or can you be certain that jQuery is loaded before `submitEvent.js`. Does the code work when using `jQuery` instead of `$`, e.g. `jQuery(document)`? How do you build your script?

Comment: @idleberg Hello, thanks to visit my problem. So, i try to answer at your question. mh. The jquery scripts is loaded correctly cause it works when i try to use in my webpage. I tried to change $ with jQuery at the top  like u said. and give the same  error.   Maybe is my build file

Comment: @idleberg is like these    {
 "cmd": ["/usr/bin/node", "$file"],
 "selector": "source.js"
}

Comment: When you're in Node, you need to import/require jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A website uses jQuery differently than Node does. In the browser, jQuery is assigned to global variable (`jQuery`/`$`). Node uses `require()` or ES6 `imports` to make jQuery accessible in a script.

If you need your code to run in both, Node and the browser, you need to use a bundler such as [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [Browserify](http://browserify.org/). However, to expains these is beyond the scope of your question. I'd start by reading a tutorial and come back when you have specific questions along the way.